# Access key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, key, state

Inside my render I have a select, and for the options I use a `.map`, like this:

```
<select value={this.state.eixo} onChange={this.handleChange}>
         <option value=""></option>
         {this.state.eixos.map((item) => {
               return <option key={item.id}>{item.descricao}</option>
         })}
</select>
```

And I want the key from the option that I choose in my `handleChange` method, I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
handleChange = (event) => { this.setState({ key: event.target.value }) };
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to Set the value of the `option` to a `key:value` pair,

```
<select value={this.state.eixo} onChange={this.handleChange}>
  <option value=""></option>
  {this.state.eixos.map(item => {
    return (
      <option key={item.id} value={`${ite.id}:${item.descricao}`}>
        {item.descricao}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>;
```

Then split the `e.target.value` to get the `key` : `value` pair and update the state using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) :

```
handleChange = event => {
  const [key, value] = event.target.value.split(":");
  this.setState({ [key]: value });
};
```

If your values could contain `:` , choose another seperator.